# Autenticação com google plus no Ionic

Tags: firebase, google, autenticação, ionic4

Estou tentando criar um login com google plus no ionic 4 na plataforma android, mas está voltando sempre um erro [10], que segundo a documentação da google, é um erro de configuração, mas não encontrei onde estou errando.

O que eu fiz até agora:

1. Criei o projeto no firebase e adicionei um projeto android.
2. Habilitei Autenticação pelo google no firebase console
3. Adicionei uma impressão digital SHA-1 no firebase console, criado pelo terminal (linux).

código do login no ionic

```
async doGoogleLogin(){

  this.googlePlus.login({
    'scopes': '',
    'webClientId': 'meuWebClientId.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'offline': true 
  })
  .then(user =>{
    this.saveGoogleUser(user);

    this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
  }, err =>{

    this.presentAlert("Error Console", err);
  });

}
```

Sempre que tento fazer login, retorna um erro '10', mas não descobri o que falta ainda.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa incluir corretamente o certificado impressão digital `SHA-1`.

Tenha em mente que cada PC gera uma impressão digital SHA-1 diferente e exclusiva. Por exemplo: se você estiver trabalhando no PC do escritório e em seu PC de casa, certifique-se de gerar a impressão digital SHA-1 em cada máquina e adicioná-la às configurações do projeto no Firebase Android.

Se você adicionou uma única impressão digital SHA-1 e tentou usar Google + auth à partir de outra máquina, a autenticação falhará e você obterá o famoso `Erro 10`.

Para gerar uma chave impressão digital SHA-1 de Debug.

> No Windows:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\<user>\.android\debug.keystore
```

> No Mac OSX e Linux:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

Senha padrão: **android**

> E o resultado será algo parecido com isto:

```
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************
* The integrity of the information stored in your keystore  *
* has NOT been verified!  In order to verify its integrity, *
* you must provide your keystore password.                  *
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************

Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: May xx, xxxx
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: C=US, O=Android, CN=Android Debug
Issuer: C=US, O=Android, CN=Android Debug
Serial number: 1
Valid from: Mon May xx  13:00:59 IST 2017 until: Wed May 15 13:00:59 IST 2047
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  26:60:AC:51:D1:18:05:F4:AE:2A:82:00:0A:0C:5E:FE
         SHA1: E0:93:D6:BF:DA:16:6D:30:89:3x:F7:03:52:BC:18:12:4E:71:76:A1
         SHA256: D0:4E:0A:E8:C9:1C:68:AD:A3:E4:9B:4E:28:7E:FC:26:81:31:D6:30:EC:21:95:C0:CE:C0:70:6F:E9:EB:11:AC
         Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
         Version: 1
```

Referência: [developers.google](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)